# Leaflet Draw, Only marker showing, Lines and Polygons not visibile

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm trying to add the [Leaflet Draw library](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) / control.

I can add a marker, and it persists (and stays visible). But when I add a line or polygon they aren't visible (persisted though if I inspect the `.layers`, also check the screenshot. The element seems to be there, but it just isn't visible).

Any guidance would be highly appreciated!

**Edit**: I'm using the following code to initialize the map:

```
var elem = angular.element('#datasetLeafletMap'); //using Angular
console.log('initting map', elem[0]);


var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, { maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib });
var map = new L.Map(elem[0], { layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(52.105289405897, 5.2629891004852425), zoom: 13 });
console.log('map ready');

var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();

var coords = [new L.latLng(51.2, 4.5), new L.latLng(51.2, 4.6), new L.latLng(51.2, 4.9)];
var poly = new L.Polyline(coords, {
color: 'blue',
opacity: 1,
weight: 5
});

drawnItems.addLayer(poly);


map.addLayer(drawnItems);


var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        position: 'right',
        polygon: {
            title: 'Polygon',
            allowIntersection: false,
            drawError: {
                color: '#b00b00',
                timeout: 1000
            },
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#bada55'
            },
            showArea: true
        },
        polyline: {
            metric: false
        },
        circle: {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#662d91'
            }
        }
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
});

map.addControl(drawControl);

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'marker') {
        layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
    }

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    console.log('adding layer', layer, drawnItems);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can share the code you're using to initialize L.Draw and handle drawing?

Comment: @iH8 good point, added.

Comment: Sorry but "It just works™", at least a direct copy/paste to Plunker does using Leaflet 0.7.7 and Draw 0.2.3. Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/GQd8Y6TX7sufb5N8rQqY?p=preview Perhaps you've got some CSS coming from somewhere messing with your paths or overlaypane?

Comment: Ok, so it's related to NVD3 which I have included. That seems to mess up the polygon rendering. Thanks for thinking along!